# Color doesnt show up even though i followed instructions

Tags: html, css

```
<html lang= "en">
  <head>
        <title>Murfreesboro Regional Soccer League</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="mondernizr.custom.62074.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <h1>Murfreesboro Regional Soccer League</h1>
  </header>
        <p>Part of the North American Recreational soccer Association.</p>



        <footer>
                    <div>
                        <p id="contact">MRSL -c/o Davies Sporting Goods.
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p id="contact"> 418 N Sartoris St. - Murfreesboro, TN 37130 - (615) 555-2255</p>
                    </div>
        </footer>
  </body>
```

Here is my style.css

```
body   

                h1, {
                    background-color: orangered;
                    color:black;
                }
                #contact,{
                    background-color: green;
                    color: white;


                }
```

I have also added "" in the main code, but it doesnt show up.
I tried to adjust things here and there but when I go to my project.
Everything is just in black and white.

Comment: You have a link to the `styles.css` file while the file name is `style.css`

Comment: Ah sorry, the file name is styles.css. I was careless when typing this

Comment: Your HTML is incomplete.

Comment: So the only thing that was wrong with the code was just the comma? Is there any websites I can use to check small errors like this?

Answer (score 1):

Your css is invalid. Just remove the comma after h1 and the comma after #contact

Also, IDs should be unique, so you should use a class instead of ID for the paragraphs.

```css
h1 {
  background-color: orangered;
  color:black;
}
.contact {
  background-color: green;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Murfreesboro Regional Soccer League</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="mondernizr.custom.62074.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Murfreesboro Regional Soccer League</h1>
    </header>
    <p>Part of the North American Recreational soccer Association.</p>

    <footer>
        <div>
            <p class="contact">MRSL -c/o Davies Sporting Goods.
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="contact"> 418 N Sartoris St. - Murfreesboro, TN 37130 - (615) 555-2255</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```